# CTE passing multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

This is an extension to my previous post.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM Combination 
  WHERE Col1 = 'val' and city='karim'), 
cte2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM Combination 
  WHERE Col1 = 'val2' and city='karim') 
SELECT CONCAT(cte1.Col2, cte2.Col2) AS Result 
FROM cte1 CROSS JOIN cte2;
```

| col1 | col2 | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Val | 145 | Telang |
| val2 | 13 | Telang |
| val2 | 25 | Telang |
| val | 146 | karim |
| val2 | 124 | karim |
| val2 | 56 | karim |

Output:

| Result |
| --- |
| 14513 |
| 14525 |
| 146124 |
| 14656 |

There are multiple cities.I wanted to get combinations only for the values existing in the cities

Tried something like this, but does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM Combination 
WHERE Column1 = 'value' and city IN(select city from Combinations);
```

Comment: Please edit your queries and remove all syntax errors.

Comment: Hi edited the query just and was missing

Comment: Your quesion is not clear. Try to provide an example and desired output according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), pp. 5 and 3.

Comment: Updated the question. Hope it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `INNER` self join of the table:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c1.Col2, c2.Col2) AS Result 
FROM Combination c1 INNER JOIN Combination c2
ON c2.city = c1.city
WHERE c1.Col1 = 'val' AND c2.Col1 = 'val2';
```

Comment: but with innerjoin i cannot pass mutiple conditions

Comment: @ls440 why not? The WHERE clause is the place to set any condition that you want.

Comment: can't we add another colum 'city' to the same query ```SELECT city, CONCAT(c1.Col2, c2.Col2) as result```

Comment: @ls440 you get an error because you wrote a query that is not correct. In my query every column name is qualified by the table's alias. `city` should be `c1.city` or `c2.city`

Comment: ah yes works. thanks